# How to draw cyclic graphs in JavaScript / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

There are several questions and respective relevant answers/discussions related to '**a**cyclic graphs' and they are indeed useful. However, I did not find anything related to "cyclic graphs" and hence I choose to post this questions here.

I have some complex temporal relationships like

- a->b->c (**'a' has a path to  'c' via 'b'**)
- b->d->c
- c->e->a (Note :- here **c has a path to a via e**)

I need to represent these relations in a 'pictorial' forma. It will be nice if 'a', 'b', 'c' etc can be shown as images but that is trivial.

Do we have any JavaScript / JQuery available to represent such relations in a graph? I am open for inputs on other technologies like flex etc. but my first choice would be JQuery/JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout this JS library. This might help you.

http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Thank you ! One may want to explore following http://www.graphviz.org/ Or http://thejit.org  and http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/RGraph/example2.html